# Everlive CRUD example with Kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, everlive

Is there a full CRUD example of how to use Everlive with Kendo grid? All I could find is how to create the data source here: http://docs.telerik.com/platform/backend-services/development/javascript-sdk/kendoui/kendo-uidata-source. What is the definition for the grid itself though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out, it is from Kendo's documentation
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/everlive.html

Comment: check this out -> http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/129/Feedback/Details/88044-everlive-js-sdk-producing-blank-records